# xor symbol representation?

Tags: php, xor

PHP manual doesn't say that there is one, but... maybe there's a hidden one?

Simply, I like using `if`'s with symbolic operation representations, that way I'm sure that when searching through a document, I'll always find what I'm looking for. But with `xor` there's possibility that my code contains such a string/value or something. Like, method in template class - e**xor**cize();.

Comment: Related: [Reference - What does this symbol mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `!=` if they're both already booleans.

```
if (true != false) // xor
    ...
```

Of course, this has the same issue with getting false positives in your search results, so perhaps you can adopt a personal convention (at the risk of confusing your co-workers) of using the other PHP not-equal operator:

```
if (true <> false) // xor
    ...
```

If they're not already booleans, you'll need to cast them.

```
if (!$a <> !$b) // xor
    ...
```

---

**Edit:** After some experimentation with PHP's very lax type coercion, I give you a pseudo-operator of own creation, the `==!` operator! `$a ==! $b` is equivalent to `$a xor $b`.

```
if ('hello' ==! 0) // equivalent to ('hello' xor 0)
    ...
```

This is actually `'hello' == !0` > `'hello' == true` > `true == true` > `true`, which is why it works as `xor`. This works because when PHP compares one boolean with anything else, it [converts the second argument to boolean too](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.types).

Comment: Huh, yes, but as you said, this provides way too many search results! What would `==!` translate to?

Comment: `==!` works as a logical `xor`. `$a ==! $b` is actually `$a == !$b`, which is the same as `!$a != !$b` because PHP coerces both sides to boolean when one side is boolean.

Answer (score 6):

The exclusive-or operator in PHP is `^`.

If you want to use `xor` (in *any* language, really, not just PHP) but you're worried about searches for it finding things like `exorcize`, you could just search for `" xor "` (with a space on either side).

Or, any regular expression that prevents the surrounding text from being part of the `xor` word, such as (example only):

```
[^a-zA-Z0-9_]xor[^a-zA-Z0-9_]
```

Comment: True, but there's a chance that there are no spaces between `xor` comparison, i.e: `if(($this && $that)xor($foo && $bar))`. A rare occurance, but still can happen.

Answer (score 4):

See [bitwise operators](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php). It's the symbol `^`.

Comment: Ah, so bitwise operators == logical operators? Or there is a difference between those?

Comment: @Tom there's a distinction in that one operates with booleans and the other with integers. Still, the type-lax nature of PHP allows you to use `^` for the same purpose as `xor`.

Answer (score 3):

If you ever find yourself in a situation where the xor operator doesn't exist then you can simulate it with and, or, and not.

(A && !B) || (!A && B)  Is logically equivalent to xor.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for logical `xor`, there is no symbol equivalent.